# Invalid Argument Exception iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS programming. I got an error thats always bugging me for days. I tried Googling it but none of the answers seem to work (or it is just me not fully understanding how this stuff works).

`2014-11-10 12:45:26.858 Launchlabs Int[1502:60b] -[UIViewController buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d57960
2014-11-10 12:45:26.862 Launchlabs Int[1502:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController buttonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d57960'`

My App Delegate header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *firstScrn;
@end
```

App Delegate implementation:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize firstScrn;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    firstScrn = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = firstScrn;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)secondBtnClick:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}

-(IBAction)secondBtnClick:(id)sender
{

}
@end
```

heres the screenshot of my nib file: 
[image]

Comment: Have you properly connected your IBActions to the StoryBoard elements in view? Looks like either you haven't connected the `buttonClicked` method properly, or perhaps you have not set your view controller to use the custom class of your implementation.

Comment: iyeah..i have connected them to my view.

Comment: Have you set your view controller in the StoryBoard to use the custom implementation class?

Comment: i added a screen shot of the nib file. i think i have added them properly.

Comment: yes.it is connected to the file owner

Comment: If you create a new project in Xcode and manually recreate this setup, it still crashes? I just created one for iOS 8 SDK and it works fine. Maybe try deleting all IBAction connections and re-connecting them?

Comment: when i clicked on any of the buttons, I get errors on main.m file (@ return line).

Comment: i did try that too @remus , also changed the names,etc.

Comment: main.m has no problem. Just try to reconnect all controls once again. (main view, and both buttons)

Comment: i did. still the same .

Comment: is your view connected to file owner?

Comment: Can you create a brand new Single View application and use Main.Storyboard instead of the .xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix this in your app delegate

> //.h
>
> #import "ViewController" // import this header
>
> //@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *firstScrn;
>
> @property (strong,nonatomic) ViewController *firstScrn;
>
> //.m
>
> //firstScrn = [[UIViewController alloc]
>   initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
>
> firstScrn = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];